# Easy access C++ vector with offset index

Tags: c++, vector

I have a bunch of element data, for example 1000 data with the "tag" was started at integer number 9 so the last tag was 1008. I would create a vector that easy enough to access specific tag using vector index,

```
std::vector<double> element_data(1009)
```

but if the tag start at higher integer it would produce garbage at 0 to starting tag index (the offset).

How to overcome this kind problem? Thank you.

Comment: Just substract 9 from your tag: that's the easiest. Slightly more generic solution would be to provide two functions that convert tags to indeces and back. Even more generic is to make a functional objects that take the offset as a parameter. BTW, if you have 1000 elements that start at 9, the last one is 1008.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov that was what I'm thinking, but maybe it would be inefficient if we keep repeating the substraction operation each time and that's why I'm asking if there is another way. Ah yes, I would edit that haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::vector` is a container that stores elements indexed from 0. If 1000 is the size of your data that is known at compile-time, you may improve the design using `std::array` instead. That is something that we know without digging into the details of your application.

Let's return to your question. You have an entity that has "tags". Looks like these tags are consequent integers, and you use them as numeric values. This entity is not exactly what vector/array is. That is something that stores data in any container and provides your the access based on the tag value. Why not to use the composition?

```
class TaggedData
{
public:
    int& operator [](size_t tag) { return array[tag - 9]; }
    const int& operator [](size_t tag) const { return array[tag - 9]; }
private:
    std::array<int, 1000> array;
};
```

That is a simple implementation, you may improve it in any way. For example, you may ake these magic numbers template parameters:

```
template<size_t N, size_t OFFSET>
class TaggedData
{
public:
    int& operator [](size_t tag) { return array[tag - OFFSET]; }
    const int& operator [](size_t tag) const { return array[tag - OFFSET]; }
private:
    std::array<int, N> array;
};
```

You may make the actual container to be a template parameter as well. Later you may discover that the tags are not consequent or even not integers.

The conclusion is: only you know your task, the details of the business logic, future plans, etc., so you need to take a decision based on that.

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction operation's cost will be very hard to measure. You're basically guessing without any understanding of what costs a lot and what doesn't. On modern hardware, integer arithmetic other than division is essentially free. If you have a performance problem, you have to measure it, try solutions, and then confirm - again by measurement - that your solution did something. Otherwise, you're 99.999999% likely to completely fool yourself and waste time doing things that yield not only no performance improvement, but usually also degrade the code quality.

Again: if you think you have a performance problem, you have to have a way to benchmark it, include the benchmarks into the test suite so that you'll avoid performance regressions, and then work from there. At the very least you need to be able to profile the benchmark runs in a repeatable fashion during development.

So if you think you'd want to do something "because of performance", you need to *both* have some sort of an argument as to why you think performance plays a role, and also have a plan about how to measure it. Otherwise, you're treating the whole thing as if it was some impenetrable magic, and your incantations are just that: valiant tries at nothing. Don't go this route.

On modern platforms, the things that cost you are cache misses, branch mispredictions and data dependencies. The dependencies prevent leveraging parallel processing inherent in modern cores, the other two just make everything slow. If you want some rules of thumb, you can think of an L1 cache miss as costing more than an integer division. A complete cache miss when the cache line needs to be pulled in from RAM is enough time to render an outline of a TrueType font glyph when the code for that has hot caches and is just happily chugging away doing floating point math. And by the way: floating point division is usually cheaper than integer division (on modern Intel platforms at least).

So none of this stuff is totally intuitive without having some good background in *modern* computer architecture.

Another way to think about performance is this: if within the coming year you'll spend more time "fixing" the performance than 1/1,000-1/1,000,000x the CPU runtime you saved, you're just throwing money away - nothing you'll save in CPU time at such scales will cover your cost of working on the problem. If you spend an hour fixing performance, it better saves you between a thousand to a million CPU hours in the coming year, or you're volunteering your time to a lost cause pretty much: volunteering because the time you spend doing the work has no worth (other than perhaps educating yourself or gaining experience), and it's a lost cause because a 1000 CPU hours is close to free. Even 1000x as many CPU hours can cost less than an hour of your time, if e.g. they are paid for by the users (i.e. you're running some code in the users' browser rather than a server you get billed for).

As for producing "garbage" at offset 0: you just said that you're not using that offset for anything, so why you worry what value is stored there? You're not supposed to be reading it, right? You need to tell us the whole story: how and when you write the values into the vector, and how you read them and use them. Otherwise I have hard time imagining why you perceive what you describe as a problem. If you say that you use the index range between 9 and 1009, for example, then who cares what's at index 0. Problem solved.

Comment: I guess the performance was not the issue. At least the author doesn't even use the word "performance".

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov *maybe it would be inefficient if we keep repeating the substraction operation* - well, yes, the author doesn't literally use that word , just as I don't literally say *inefficient* in my answer . And of course the performance is not an issue because it can't be. When you subtract, the problem almost never is with the subtraction, it's to do with actually feeding the ALU with data fast enough, and storing the results fast enough, because it has so much bandwidth available to subtract, and everything else is so comparatively slow.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't see that comment.